# Manage ASP.NET Windows Service from a Web Application (browser)

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

I have number of windows service (around 10) all are developed in ASP.NET C#. And are installed on Windows Web Server 2008. If I wanted to start or stop the service I have to log in to the Windows Web Server and then Start/Stop the service.

[image]

I wanted to manage this activity through a Web Portal which I wants to create in ASP.NET C#.

Does anybody any idea or have any reference that how it can be done?

Comment: First, are you talking about a server that exists in a hosting provider outside of your network?  Or is it a server that's somewhere in your network?  Because if it's in your network, you don't need to create a web server to do this, there are various GUI and command line tools to manage services remotely.

Comment: Hi Erik, my services are running on same network. I just don't want to log in into the server to start the web service.

Comment: Then you can use a number of built-in functions, like the sc.exe command line, or use the Services.msc snap-in then go to Action->Connect to another computer, or install the Windows Administrator tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a web service that controls the service via rest calls and run that web service on the server. Then use jquery to make rest calls from a web page ( on that server) using $.post() or $.ajax() or JavaScript native xmlhttprequest

Visual studio web has project templates for web services that can get you started. The service start stop can be using this example

http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/

Answer (score 2):

If your web portal will be published on the same machine with services than you can use ServiceController class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx